# Rails 5 test doesn't reproduce actual behaviour on PATCH

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, devise

I'm really stuck here. I have a `Language` model, that gets updated in this method:

```
  def update
    @language = Language.find(params[:id])

    if @language.update_attributes(language_params)
      flash[:success] = 'Language information updated.'
      redirect_to @language
    else
      @skill_errors = @language.errors
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

The intended behaviour for a successful update reproduces when I run it on my local server, object gets updated, flash appears and redirect to `@language` happens.

In the test, however, I only get the `200: Success` response, and the object doesn't get updated. Here's the test code:

```
  test 'should allow update when logged in as admin user' do
    sign_in(@admin)
    patch language_path(@ruby_language), params: { language: { name: 'Test'} }
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to @ruby_language
    @ruby_language.reload
    assert_equal 'Test', @ruby_language.name
  end
```

`@admin` and `@ruby_language` are defined in fixtures. All the asserts in this test fail, including the last one, with `reload`. My guess is that there might be some routing glitch caused by my usage of `Devise` and/or `Kaminari` gems? On the other hand, my `Language` routes are very simple:
`resources :languages, concerns: :paginatable` (the concern is here for human-readable URL formatting). Please, keep in mind that everything works as intended, only tests fail for some reason... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add `puts @response.body` after calling the `patch` method and post the output here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out I was simply missing a required parameter in my update hash. Used Arun Kumar's tip of adding `puts @response.body` after `patch`.